# ajax autocomplete extender is not working

Tags: asp.net, ajax, autocomplete

I have an autocompleate extender on textbox which shows records as a list from database but whern I click on texbox and start typing nothing happned. my html code is

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:AutoCompleteExtender ID="TextBox1_AutoCompleteExtender" runat="server" 
         Enabled="True"  TargetControlID="TextBox1" ServicePath="~/WebService.asmx" 
                ServiceMethod="GetCompletionList"
                MinimumPrefixLength="2" 
                CompletionInterval="1000"
                EnableCaching="true"
                CompletionSetCount="20"
                DelimiterCharacters=";, :"
                ShowOnlyCurrentWordInCompletionListItem="true" >
    </asp:AutoCompleteExtender>
```

And my web service is

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.Services;
    using System.Data;
    using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
    using System.Configuration;

     /// <summary>
     /// Summary description for WebService
    /// </summary>
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
    // [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
     public class WebService : System.Web.Services.WebService {

    public WebService () {

        //Uncomment the following line if using designed components 
        //InitializeComponent(); 
    }

    [WebMethod]
    public static List<string> GetCompletionList(string prefixText, int count)
    {
        MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["cn"]);
        if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            con.Open();
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT gotra FROM tbgotra WHERE gotra LIKE '%" + prefixText + "%'",con);
        List<string> k = new List<string>();
        using (MySqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (sdr.Read())
            {
                k.Add(sdr["gotra"].ToString());
            }
        }
        con.Close();
        return k;
    }
   }
```

Comment: Can you put the database.asmx code also?

Comment: I'm calling list of object from database by my service method. which is given above.

Comment: IM sorry i mean the Webservice.asmx file, just want to make sure that it was correct.

Comment: ok i'll post the whole file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding this line, i remember i had the same problem once where it worked for me locally but not live.

```
[WebMethod]
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod] <-- Add this line
public static List<string> GetCompletionList(string prefixText, int count)
....
```

Comment: thanks for answering kay but doesn't work in my case

Comment: Do you have any error handling? Do you know that the function is actually being runned? Try just adding a line of code to create a file on the server and make sure its being created, this to Ensure that the function runs at all. Or but a breakpoint in the code in debug mode...

Comment: there is no error handling, I think i should try to change the package of ajax control toolkit

Comment: Have you tried to put the entire GetCompletionList function in your code behind page where the textbox is just to try and see if it works there?

Comment: I tried it by both page method and service method but nothing worked

Comment: Ok you have to add some kind of error handling to start the debug. It could be many possible errors.

Comment: I think this is toolkit version error. I am using visual studio 2010.

Comment: I done it by replacing my ajax referance. I was using ajax for vs2012. thanks for your help kay.

Comment: Ok good! I would advice in the future to implement some error handling, can save you time :)

Comment: You can combine the attributes like so as well: [WebMethod(), ScriptMethod()]

Answer (score 0):

you Should to use

```
<asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
```

in before the TextBox1

Comment: Where is this asp:ToolkitScriptManager I can find no reference to it anywhere ?

Comment: just copy this sample and change attribute and used.

Answer (score 0):

try this signature for web method:

`public string[] GetCompletionList(string prefixText, int count, string contextKey)` 

I think extender wont accept any other return type besides string[]

Comment: using context key argument is optional.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had to un-comment this line in the ASMX file

```
// To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line.
// [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was issue with the css class below, I've had it in the source but without z-index property.

```
<ajaxToolkit:AutoCompleteExtender ID="AutoCompleteExtender2" runat="server" 
ClientIDMode="Static" MinimumPrefixLength="1" ServiceMethod="GetAllStaff" 
TargetControlID="txtTeacherName" ServicePath="~/webservices/WebService.asmx" 
CompletionInterval="50" EnableCaching="true" CompletionSetCount="20" 
ShowOnlyCurrentWordInCompletionListItem="true" 
CompletionListCssClass="CompletionListCssClass">
</ajaxToolkit:AutoCompleteExtender>
   
<style>
.CompletionListCssClass {
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #000;
    padding: 3px 5px;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    background: #fff;
    width: 300px;
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 0;
    overflow: auto;
    height: 200px;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 10000001 !important;
}
</style>
```